# Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ of index $2$ .Then show that if $a,b\notin H$ then $ab\in H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be  a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ of index $2$ .Then show that if $a,b\notin H$ then $ab\in H$.

$a,b\notin H\implies aH,bH\neq H\implies $
$aH=bH$  since $H$ has only two distinct left cosets in $G$.

$\implies a^{-1}b\in H$

How to show that $ab\in H$ from here?

Comment: Don't forget to apply this to concluding that one of $-1,2,-2$ is a quadratic residue modulo a prime!

Comment: @jyrki Yes I will apply it

Comment: The reason $aH,bH\neq H$ because of $H$ having two distinct left cosets is due to the fact that $H$ itself is a left coset? Or can you please explain why $aH=bH$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From $a\not\in H$ we obtain $a^{-1}\not\in H$ because $H$ is a subgroup. Then your argument gives $ab=(a^{-1})^{-1}b\in H$.